# laravel file system upload to resources/views directory

Tags: laravel

I am developing CMS by laravel and have layout module which should upload blades files (Blade Templates) to resources/views.

so my question is how to change it from storage/app to resources/views.

Comment: Change what?  Show your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it is documented [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#the-local-driver), you can add disk instances in `./project/config/filesystems.php`
 like this

```
'disks' => [
    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],
    'resources_views' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => base_path('resources/views'),
    ],
],
```

And in your controller, when getting or uploading files, specify the disk,

```
Storage::disk("resources_views")->get("app.blade.php");
```

Comment: So, any feedback ?

Comment: thanks it works now, i can use also resource_path(), i found the answer in helper func. thanks bro for your help

Comment: Oops, you're right, there is a helper for that, https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers